# Calculate correlation in R between numeric and character columns

Tags: r, correlation, redundancy

I would like to know how can i calculate the correlation between all the columns of my data.set that have some of them numeric and most of them character and integer. My data is composed by 6000 obs. of 23 variables. After calculating the correlation i also would like to delete the redundant columns, in order to create a better data.set

Comment: Can you provide more detail about your redundant columns? What makes them redundant?

Comment: There are 6 columns that i think should be useless, and are OnlineSecurity, OnlineBackup, DeviceProtection, TechSupport, StreamingTV and StreamingMovies. They got all Yes/No/No internet service value and i wanted to see their correlation with churn column and deep understand if i could eliminate them. Hope that i gave a useful details here.

Comment: If you're comparing categorical versus continuous data, ANOVA is probably a better alternative to Pearson's correlation coefficient. I suggest looking into this post to learn more: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/108007/correlations-with-categorical-variables

Comment: You could use Boruta package in R for this purpose. It takes all of your Cotegorical, Character and Numeric variables and gives your detailed correlation. Follow this tutorial here: https://www.analyticsvidhya.com/blog/2016/03/select-important-variables-boruta-package/

Answer (score 1):

You can simply use the `cor()` function on the entire data frame to create the correlation matrix. **However, by definition, correlation coefficients can only be computed on numeric values.** Character and integer values are not allowed. I recommend going to the Stats Exchange site to learn more about correlation coefficients.

```
cor(df)
```

Comment: As you said cor() is only viable for numeric fields, so i can not use it in this situation, another solution?